# Change font size relative to current font size

Tags: fontsize

For some small macros I'm writing I would need to change the font size relative to the font size of the text that surrounds to macro later on.
I only know how to change the font size for the whole document (documentclass/fontspec), or for some text, but only relative to the default font size for the document (`\Large`, `\small)`.

What I was thinking of was something like:

```
\newcommand*\mycommand{\smaller ipsum}
\Large lorem \mycommand
\small lorem \mycommand
```

If I use `\Large`, `\small` etc in the command itself, it will not care about the font size of the surrounding text but set the font size relative to the default font size. I would want it to be e.g. 1.2 times smaller than `\Large` or `\small`, depending on where it is used.

Comment: IMO, adding the [tag:macro] tag or not was a close call here.

Comment: After reading the tag description a second time (for another question) I though that it did not fit since the question was not on the "mechanics" of macros, but rather on a specific macro. But you are right...we surely could discuss this

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Have a look at the [`relsize`](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) package. Package description:

> The basic command of the package is `\relsize`, whose argument is a
>   number of `\magstep`s to change size; from this are defined commands
>   `\larger`, `\smaller`, `\textlarger`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I had stumbled upon this package on some webpage, but the description there was so bad that I thought it was something immitating `\Large` etc.

Comment: The AMS classes (`amsart` and `amsbook`) have a similar built-in mechanism.