# Change font size in context by percentage

Tags: fontsize

Font sizes can be set with (more or less) absolute commands such as `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, and so on.

Are there also commands that can increase or reduce a font size by some proportion or percentage not in absolute terms but relative to the preceding text?

I am hoping to find a way to do this in the midst of chapter titles, which are set in the preamble to be `\LARGE\bfseries`. But when a colon appears in a chapter title, followed by a subtitle, I am being asked to reduce the size of the subtitle by just a small amount — and the result of using the absolute `\Large` is not satisfactory. I could redefine `\Large` just for this situation, but I'd prefer to find a *relative* command to change font size, as described above, as that would be useful in many other situations.

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56676/change-font-size-relative-to-current-font-size) useful.

Comment: To scale only a few characters, the tikz package can do it. `Sub%
\tikz[inner sep=0pt] \node[minimum size=0, scale=0.6] {t};%
otal`

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to the hint from Brent.Longborough, I found the `relsize` package, which does what is required.

The package allows relative resizing of fonts: normally, resizing is done to the ten fixed "sizing commands" (`\Large` etc.). To go to the next whole size up one uses `\larger` or `\relsize{1}`, to the next whole size down `\smaller` or `\relsize{-1}`.

The interesting thing is that fine control of this kind can be attained with the commands `\relscale{〈factor〉}` and `\text-scale{〈factor〉}{〈text〉}`, where `〈factor〉` can be a non-integer decimal number.

In addition, `\relsize` also accepts a non-integer factor as argument: `\relsize{0.8}` (not mentioned in the 20030704 documentation).

Examples below, all showing a `\LARGE` chapter title with the font reduced after the colon:

- Font reduced using `\Large{〈text〉}` or `\smaller` or `\relsize{-1}`:
  [image: Example with whole-step-down sizing]
- Font reduced using `\relscale{0.9}`:
  [image: Example with fractional <code>\relscale</code>]
- Font reduced using `\relsize{-0.8}`:
  [image: Example with fractional <code>\relsize</code>]