# How can I redefine a character such as the (actual text) dollar sign?

Tags: fontsize

I am using text/old-style figures in my document with the Palatino font, and I find that the dollar sign (`\$`) is too large for most dollar figures. I've found that it looks good if I take the font size of just the dollar sign down by one, like so:

`{\small\$}1,000`

But this is a pain, so I'd like to change `\$` so it handles the size shift automatically.

My immediate thought was to do `\def\${{\small\$}}`, but obviously (obvious after you've naïvely tried it anyway), that results in infinite recursion. What sort of control sequence can I use to represent the font dollar sign other than `\$`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possibility; we have just to redefine `\textdollar` (and possibly `\mathdollar`, if you plan to use it in math). I scale it vertically, but not horizontally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareTextCommand{\textdollar}{T1}{\scalebox{1}[.85]{\symbol{`\$}}}

\begin{document}

\$100 or \$600

{\footnotesize \$100 or \$600}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note. The command `\$` is defined (with the `T1` encoding) to either do `\textdollar` or `\mathdollar`, depending on the context. So there's no need to redefine `\$`.

Answer (score 2):

Store the original copy of `\$` and then redefine it to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\olddollar\$% Store \$
\begin{document}

This solution is worth \$0.02.

\renewcommand{\$}{{\small\olddollar}}%
This solution is worth \$0.02.

\end{document}
```

Note though that this change may not work as expected when using `\$` inside (say) a `\footnote`. For that you should consider the *relative* font size of `$` inside `\normalsize`. That is, `\small` is "one size smaller" than `\normalsize`. The [`relsize` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) offers `\smaller` which would help here. See [Change font size relative to current font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56676/5764).

Comment: Oh, duh :-)

Thanks for the tip on `relsize` – I don't anticipate ever using a dollar sign in anything except running text, but it's always better to head off possible problems ahead of time. So in the end I used

``\usepackage{relsize} / 
\let\olddollar\$ / 
\renewcommand\${{\relsize{-0.5}\olddollar}}``

Comment: @SorenBjornstad: Use `\renewcommand{\$}{{\smaller\$}}`.

Comment: Unless I've misread it, according to the docs, `\smaller` is equivalent to `\relsize{-1}`, which is not what I want – that takes it down to 8 point rather than the 9 point value of `\small`.

Comment: @SorenBjornstad: `\smaller` is equivalent to `\smaller[1]` which is equivalent to `\relsize{-1}`, which prints `\small` under `\normalsize`, whatever your `\normalsize` is. If `\normalsize` is 10pt, then `\small` is 9pt. See [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764)

Comment: I'm not trying to be contrary (and thanks for your help!), but they are definitely not identical. The docs say: "Half-steps are possible, as in \relsize{-0.5} to change from 10 pt \normalsize to 9 pt \small, but other numbers are rounded to the nearest half-integer." `\smaller` yields a smaller dollar sign than `\relsize{-0.5}` (and the dollar sign produced by the latter looks superior in terms of size to my eyes). If I zoom to 500% in my PDF viewer and measure, the unmodified $ is 38pt high, the \relsize{-0.5} and the {\small\$} are both 34pt high, and the \smaller sign is 30pt high.

Comment: @SorenBjornstad: Sure, go for it! To obtain various mid-step sizes, you may have to use `lmodern`.

Comment: I guess it maybe doesn't matter, but I'm not clear on how this is a "mid-step size" – the size I get with `\relsize{-0.5}` is exactly identical to what I get from `\small`.

Comment: @SorenBjornstad: You're right. Strange; I was expecting something different; I checked `\${\small\$}{\smaller\$}{\relsize{-1}\$}{\relsize{-0.5}\$}`. Use what suits you best.